# Issues with ui-router routing with dynamic url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have email verification state defined as below, which redirects the state to account if the user is logged in and otherwise it opens up, but the thing is with dynamic params of verification url.

```
 $stateProvider
.state('verification', {
  url: '/verification/:email/:token',
  templateUrl: 'verification/verification.tpl.html',
  controller: 'VerificationCtrl',
  title: 'Verification',
  resolve: {
    UnauthenticatedUser: ['$q', '$state', 'securityAuthorization', function($q, $state, securityAuthorization){
      var promise = securityAuthorization.requireUnauthenticatedUser()
        .catch(function(){
          // user is authenticated, redirect
          $state.go('account.dashboard');
          return $q.reject();
        });
      return promise;
    }]
  }
});
```

In this case it should redirect to account.dashboard(/account/dashboard), but it bounce back to this url(/verification/:email/:token) after that.

But if I put the url as `/verification` only then it works normally the way it is supposed to and redirect to account.dashboard. 
Can someone suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: add your code for the ui router navigation.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? If the user is unauthenticated you send them to account.dashboard state? Also you have written your $state.go() iside the .catch() loop instead of .then() is that correct?

Comment: My code is for ui router navigation. If user is unauthenticated it should show the current url, if he is not, that mean he is authenticated(logged in) then requireUnauthenticated User throw error, and then it navigated to his account/dashboard page.